# How to inverse the last Y bits and get positive number?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need to inverse the Y bits from the right to left, after removing Z from right to left.

x and y = 2;
16 in binary - 10000. Removing the last 2 bits(z) we get 100. Now I need to reverse the last 2 zeros, so the result will be 3 in decimal. Could you help me? I can't extract only the last 2(y) to invert them and then add them to the remaining one bit.

```
int x = 16; // 10000
int y = 2;
int z= 2;
x = x>>z;
// x = 100
//inverse the last 2(y), 00 -> 11;
//print 3(11)
```

Comment: you can inverse bit number i with x = x ^ (1 << i)

Comment: I'm not sure what the final result should be. `111` is `7` in decimal.

Comment: What you describe and the examples you give contradict. Please explain more and show more examples.

Comment: My bad, i edited it.

Comment: You say you want `3` as the answer - but why? Do you then want to invert the lowest 2 bits **and then clear** all the other (upper) bits? If so, I can modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: When i remove the last 2 i got 100. Then i take and invert last 2, the first bit is ignored. So 100, i take the last two (00), and invert them - 11, result 3.  I made a mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [exclusive or (XOR) operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_%5E) between a target bit and `1` will invert the target bit; furthermore, you can do this operation on any set of bits in a given variable (64- 32- and 16-bit `int` or byte) by using a [bit mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to specify which bits to flip (setting those bits in the mask) - other bits (i.e those with `0` in the mask) will be left unchanged.

You can also use a bit mask with the [bitwise AND operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_&) to clear any specific bits; in this case, those bits corresponding to a `1` in the mask will be left *unchanged*, whereas those corresponding to a `0` in the mask will be *cleared*.

So, the last two bits can be flipped by XORing the target with the value `3` (which is `...00011` in binary); then, you can clear all other bits by using the `&` operator (in this case, the mask will be the same).

Thus, this code will do what you want:

```cpp
int x = 16; // 10000
int y = 2;
int z= 2;
x = x >> z;// Shifts out (removes) the low 'z' bits
x = x ^ 3; // Flips the last two bits ("^" is the XOR operator)
x = x & 3; // Clears all BUT the last two bits
```

Or, more succinctly:

```cpp
x = ( (x >> z) ^ 3 ) & 3;
```

Note: If you want to change the low **2** bits to a variable number of bits (i.e. to `z`, as you have with the shift operator), then you can construct the bit mask using the knowledge that 2<sup>z</sup> - 1 will be the numerical value of that mask. You can get this value into a variable, `mask` by left-shifting the number `1` by `z` (a single left-shift is *generally* equivalent to multiplication by 2, for small *positive* numbers) then subtracting `1`:

```cpp
int mask = (1 << z ) - 1;
```

Then you can use `mask` in place of the 'fixed' value of `3` in the above code:

```cpp
x = ( (x >> z) ^ mask ) & mask;
```

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Proper Programming *is* a kind of magic!  ‎